# Add columns using tidyverse language, but use column numbers instead of column names

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(col1 = c(5, 2), col2 = c(6, 4), col3 = c(9, 9))
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#    col1  col2  col3
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     5     6     9
# 2     2     4     9
```

I need to add columns 1 and 3. But the column names often change. So I can only use column numbers as opposed to the actual column name.

Attempt 1 works as expected.
Attempt 2 and 3 don't work.

What's wrong with my syntax? I can't use attempt 1 because next month the column names may be something else, but their relative positions will remain the same.

```
df %>% mutate(col4 = col1 + col3)        # attempt 1
df %>% mutate(col4 = .[, 1] + .[, 3])    # attempt 2
df %>% {mutate(col4 = .[, 1] + .[, 3])}  # attempt 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is based on position, use `rowSums` by subsetting the columns based on the column index.  The advantage is that we can also take care of `NA` elements (if any)

```
df %>% 
  mutate(col4 = rowSums(.[c(1, 3)], na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#   col1  col2  col3  col4
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     5     6     9    14
#2     2     4     9    11
```

---

Regarding the issue in OP's case, we need `[[` instead of `[` for subsetting a single column as a `vector`.  With `df[, 1]` or `.[,1]` it would still be a `tibble` with one column instead of converting to a `vector` as we think about the behavior we find with `data.frame`

```
df %>% 
     mutate(col4 = .[[1]] + .[[3]])
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#   col1  col2  col3  col4
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     5     6     9    14
#2     2     4     9    11
```